# Can I use tensorflow c++ library (compiled in vs2019) in vs2015?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I recently try to use tensorflow c++ to speed up my model in C application. I used [fragguly-deep](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep) in my project. But my company was not satisfied with the speed. I tried to compile tensorflow in c++ to apply gpu acceleration but I failed during bazel build.

```
ERROR: C:/users/user/_bazel_user/sd7zocps/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:155:11: C++ compilation of rule '@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf' failed (Exit -1): python.exe failed: error executing command
  cd C:/users/user/_bazel_user/sd7zocps/execroot/org_tensorflow
  SET CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2
    SET INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt;
    SET LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64;
    SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\;;C:\Windows\system32
    SET PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    SET PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe
    SET PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages
    SET RUNFILES_MANIFEST_ONLY=1
    SET TEMP=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
    SET TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
    SET TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=8.6
    SET TMP=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
  C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe -B external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/windows/msvc_wrapper_for_nvcc.py /nologo /DCOMPILER_MSVC /DNOMINMAX /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS /bigobj /Zm500 /J /Gy /GF /EHsc /wd4351 /wd4291 /wd4250 /wd4996 /Iexternal/com_google_protobuf /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf /Iexternal/com_google_protobuf/src /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src /showIncludes /MD /O2 /DNDEBUG /W0 /D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DNOGDI /experimental:preprocessor /d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions /arch:AVX /std:c++14 /DHAVE_PTHREAD /wd4018 /wd4065 /wd4146 /wd4244 /wd4251 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4307 /wd4309 /wd4334 /wd4355 /wd4506 /wd4514 /wd4800 /wd4996 /Fobazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/_objs/protobuf/printer.obj /c external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/io/printer.cc
Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 11.077s, Critical Path: 1.69s
INFO: 30 processes: 30 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I thought that was caused by vs version. My company is using vs 2015 but [tensorflow offically said it should be compiled with vs 2019](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows). So my question is if I can use tensorflow compiled in vs 2019 in vs 2015. Or actually that is not the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Before recompiling tensorflow, you want to check if it's a release build without gpu debugging symbols (it does slow down a lot your application), if it's adapted to your hardware, and you want to profile your application, to see how the hardware is being used (eg., nsight systems for nvidia's gpus). I think recompiling TF can be useful if you need to support a new hardware feature for instance (eg., with a new generation of gpu, and compute calpabilities) or another c++ toolchain. Also you can recompile with vs2019 with 2015's toolchain, and use the binaires with vs2015 (a bit old...).

Comment: Also in general, you really want to use the recommended build tools, because the OSS teams will support those, and likely won't give you support for old tools, so you're diving into some endless chains of errors. Also, you might want to suggest your company to move to VS2019.

Comment: @Soleil Thanks a lot! I discussed with my team. They want me to compile TF with vs2019 and to build functions as DLL to check if I can link that in vs2015 project. If that fails, we may apply further works.

Comment: Since you're targeting Ampere architecture, and seeking performance, you might as well upgrade to cuda 11.5 and cudnn 8.2. Not expensive. Later *nsight systems* will be your best friend for profiling.